# Extract only a specific text in excel in a machine generated chat transcript

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a machine generated chat data exported to excel as below

**User:** I need help in cancelling my order

**Agent:** Sure I can assist you on that

**User:** cool

**User:** Also, I need your support in ordering some other item

**User:** I don't know how to do that

**Agent:** Sure, I'll help with all your queries

I'm trying to extract only the user text from the above conversation from each cell into a seperate cell in excel

I tried all known methods to the best of my knowledge to get it.   Unfortunately, unable to do so. Please help me achieving this.

Sample output:

I want to extract only user typed message to a different cell from the above conversation like below

User: I need help in cancelling my order
User: cool
User: Also, I need your support in ordering some other item
User: I don't know how to do that

Comment: Is every back and forth in it's own cell or do multiple User chats exist within a single cell? Can you give us a better sense of how the data is structured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If VBA UDF is an option then we can use regular expressions like ...

```
Option Explicit

Function ExtractUserChat(ChatString As String) As String

Dim regex As Object, mc As Object, result As String, i As Long

Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.regexp")
regex.ignorecase = False
regex.Global = True

regex.Pattern = "User: "
ChatString = regex.Replace(ChatString, "{<<USER>>: ")
'Or if you want each submatch on next line then
'ChatString = regex.Replace(ChatString, "{" & Chr(10) & "USER>>: ")

regex.Pattern = "Agent: "
ChatString = regex.Replace(ChatString, "}Agent: ") & "}"

regex.Pattern = "\{[^}]+\}"
Set mc = regex.Execute(ChatString)
result = ""

For i = 0 To mc.Count - 1
    result = result & mc(i)
Next i
result = Replace(Replace(result, "{", ""), "}", "")

ExtractUserChat = result

End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the text string appears in a single cell, then `FILTERXML` might help (see  [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/text-split-to-array), for example).

I was able to get the desired result by using `FILTERXML` together with the the `LET` function:

```
=IFERROR(LET(
X, FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE($A$1, "User:", "</s><s>")&"</s></t>", "//s"),
Y, IFERROR(SEARCH("Agent:", X)-2, LEN(X)),
"User: "&LEFT(X,Y)),
"")
```

[image]

Working step-by-step:

1. `FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE($A$1, "User:", "</s><s>")&"</s></t>", "//s")`creates a dynamic array of the string, splitting the text into different rows whenever `"User:"` appears in the string.
2. Where `X` represents the value of each cell in the dynamic array generated in step 1, `IFERROR(SEARCH("Agent:", X)-2, LEN(X))` returns either the position of the string `"Agent:"` within `X` or the length of `X`.
3. Using the `LET` function, we call step 1 `X` and step 2 `Y`. Then our output is the left-most `Y` characters of `X`, prepended with the string `"User: "` (to account for its removal in step 1).
4. We wrap the entire function in an `IFERROR` to maintain best practice .

Note that if you want the output in a single cell rather than multiple, you can simply join the cells together with `TEXTJOIN`. Something like the below would do the trick.

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, IFERROR(LET(
X, FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE($A$1, "User:", "</s><s>")&"</s></t>", "//s"),
Y, IFERROR(SEARCH("Agent:", X)-2, LEN(X)),
"User: "&LEFT(X,Y)),
""))
```

[image]